# DB2 coalesce function return null on substring

Tags: sql, db2

Running into a problem using DB2 on iSeries V7R4.

Would like to split a varchar into 2 variables (in this examples the *into*s are missing, but doesn't matter).

`select coalesce(null, 'DATA') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;` => `DATA` as expected.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR('ABC.DEF', 1, LOCATE('.','ABC.DEF')-1) as FIRST_PART
  , SUBSTR('ABC.DEF', LOCATE('.','ABC.DEF')+1)   as SECOND_PART
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

=> {`ABC`, `DEF`} as expected.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR('ABCDEF', 1, LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')-1) as FIRST_PART
  , SUBSTR('ABCDEF', LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')+1)   as SECOND_PART
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

=> {`<null>`, `ABCDEF`} as expected.

```
SELECT
    coalesce(SUBSTR('ABCDEF', 1, LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')-1), 'DATA') as FIRST_PART
  , SUBSTR('ABCDEF', LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')+1)   as SECOND_PART
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

=> still  {`<null>`, `ABCDEF`}, not {`DATA`, `ABCDEF`} as expected.

Any idea how to get a char or varchar splittet into 2 colums by only one separator?

Comment: Are you certain the behavior of the third query is reproducible?

Comment: Yeah, you and @Charles are right. Didn't noticed the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the warnings returned when running the 3rd statement.

> Argument *N of substringing function not valid. Cause . . . . . :  
> Argument 2 or 3 of the SUBSTRING function, argument 2 of the LEFT
> function, or argument 3 of the OVERLAY function is either out of range
> or is an expression that does not evaluate to an integer.

`LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')` returns 0, so the third argument ends up being -1 which is not valid.

`CASE` is probably a better choice than `COALESCE`

```
SELECT
    case LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')
      when 0 then 'DATA'
      else SUBSTR('ABCDEF', 1,LOCATE('.','ABCDEF') -1)
    end  
  , SUBSTR('ABCDEF', LOCATE('.','ABCDEF')+1)   as SECOND_PART
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```